# Materialized view refresh with 2 billion data

Tags: oracle, olap

I have a huge database with 200gb records (2.2 billion data) and strong hardware (16 cpu 32 gb ram) Oracle. I need to query over this huge data in these dimensions. Every hour 200.000 new records adding to my fact table

time --> year , month, day , hour
business1 --> 4 level
business2 --> 3 level
subscriber --> 1 million

business1 and business2 matches in same lowest level called ad_variation
1 service_record table (2 billion data)

service_record includes time in timestamp, subscriber Id, ad_variation_id

For querying over these huge system I used 62 materialized view but system sometimes gives problem such as `12008: ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path`.

my system 
service_record (2 billion data)
|
my_cube  ( service_record group by time , ad_variation_id, subscriber ) (500 million data)
|
business1_hour all level( my_cube group by trunc(time,hour) , business1_levels ,subscriber)
(200million - 600 milion data)
|
business2_hour_all level( my_cube group by trunc(time,hour) , business2_levels ,subscriber)
(200million - 600 milion data)
 
|
business2_day all level( business1_hour group by trunc(time,day) , business1_levels ,subscriber)
(30million - 50 milion data)
|
business2_day_all level( business2_hour group by trunc(time,day) , business2_levels ,subscriber)
(30million - 50 milion data)
 
|
time_levels

Does anyone can offer me how can I improve or solve refresh problems?

Oracle version : 10g

service_Record table:

create table  SERVICE_RECORD parallel 16 storage (initial 1M next 10M) 
 partition by range( servicetime ) 
 (
daily  partition
 )  as 
 select s.id, s.servicetime , s.advariationId , s.blindId, s.action
 from tap_prod.service_Record s where s.servicetime > to_date('01/01/2012','dd/MM/yyyy');

my main group by data :
CREATE materialized VIEW tap_cube  
 parallel 16  storage (initial 1M next 10M) 
 partition by range( service_time ) 
 (daily partition )
 build immediate  refresh fast on demand
AS
SELECT TRUNC (sr.servicetime,'HH') as service_time,
            sr.advariationid AS ad_variation_id,
            sr.blindid AS blind_id,
            COUNT (sr.blindid) AS total_impr,
            SUM (sr.action) AS total_action , count(sr.action) as col1 , 
count(*) as col2 
     FROM  service_record sr   
    group by TRUNC (sr.servicetime,'HH'), sr.advariationid, sr.blindid;

my business1 logic table :

business level 1:

create materialized view cube_ty_1_adv_1_time_4
 parallel 16  storage (initial 10M next 100M)
partition by range( service_time ) 
 ( daily_partition
)   
 build immediate  refresh fast on demand
as
SELECT  
        CAST (mycube.service_time AS TIMESTAMP) AS service_time,
    ADV.broker_id as entity_id,    
    blind_id,
    SUM (total_impr) as total_impr,count(total_impr)  col3 ,
    SUM (total_action) as total_action  , count(total_action) as col1  , count(*) as col2 
     FROM tap_cube mycube, dim_advertisement adv
    WHERE mycube.ad_variation_id = adv.ad_variation_id
group by CAST (mycube.service_time AS TIMESTAMP), ADV.broker_id, blind_id;

business 1 dimension level :

CREATE table 
    dim_advertisement
 AS
 SELECT bro.id AS broker_id,
  adver.id AS advertiser_id,
  camp.id AS campaign_id,
  adv.id AS advertisement_id,
  ad.id AS ad_variation_id
 FROM 
  tap_prod.advertisement adv,
  tap_prod.ad_variation ad,
  tap_prod.campaign camp,
  tap_prod.advertiser adver,
  tap_prod.broker bro
  WHERE 
    bro.id = adver.brokerid
   and  camp.advertiserid = adver.id 
  AND camp.id = adv.campaignid
   and  ad.advertisementid = adv.id;

Comment: what type of MV? what version of Oracle? put an example of MV.

Comment: I thought you had a table with 2bn records... this should be doable. I think we need a lot more information about what's going on. What the code is for the MVs that have a problem and what the change velocity is when you have a problem etc.

Comment: Oracle version is 10g . This application is an advertisement management system. Every hour 200.000 new banner is viewed by subscribers. Our aim to take report result over how many subscriber and unique subscriber has seen banners at time space(year,month,day,hour) levels  .

Answer (score 0):

General advice:

1. keep an eye on your PGA and buffer cache advisories to get the balance right.
2. the most common cause of poor performance in Oracle data warehouses that I've seen is poor i/o throughput. You don't mention your read/write bandwidth but you should know and quote that.
3. There are at least three MV refresh mechanisms -- MV log, direct path log, and partition change tracking. They are very different and the one(s) in use depend on your data load mechanism. Let us have more information on that.
4. 62 MV's is more than I've previously seen. If your MV's all refresh in one transaction then you'll have difficulty in monitoring and diagnosing it without turning on 10046-style tracing or using a tool such as AWR. MV refresh has not in my experience always been the most efficient process, and it could be worth looking at manual maintenance of the summary tables to improve performance.